# Prototype Javascript: getting an elements width as an integer

Tags: javascript, image, prototypejs

for mobile version of my site, I need to change the size of my icons.

This way I give those Icons that are too small the class "icon".

Then I iterate all img.icon's and want to change their size:

```
$$("img.icon").each(function (e) {
  // what to do now? e.setStyle({width: (e.width * 2).toString() + "px"});
});
```

How do I get the width and height of an image in pixels as an integer?

Thanks, yours Joern.

Comment: the pseudo code example in the comment doesn't work, because `e.width` and `e.height` is sometimes `0`

Comment: @Joem Do you mean the width and height are `0` before the image has loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
e.setStyle({width: (e.getDimensions().width * 2).toString() + "px"});
```

Also, like @clockworkgeek said, make sure to place the above code in a function that waits for the DOM to be loaded, and the image as well.

Comment: looked promising but didn't work. will close this, solved it by setting every `img.icon` in the CSS as 64x64px..